# Is it possible to keep single-line comments? (Writing greasemonkey/userscripts in CoffeeScript)

Tags: javascript, comments, greasemonkey, coffeescript, userscripts

I've noticed that when compiling CoffeeScript, none of the single-line comments are retained.

This is problematic as I'm trying to write a greasemonkey/userscript in CoffeeScript, and they rely on comments for the metadata block.

I've tried using backticks, but there seems to be a problem with backticks around comments:

```
`// ==UserScript==
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==`

alert "hello world"
```

Becomes

```
// ==UserScript==
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==;alert("hello world");
```

And if I add an extra line before the closing backtick I get:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==
;alert("hello world");
```

It would also be nice to have the convenience of automatic wrapping.. but I suppose without `-bare` the metadata block would be wrapped as well.

Is there a better way I could be going about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't use CoffeeScript, but from the docs it looks like you could use:

```
###
// ==UserScript==
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==
###
alert "hello world"
```

Which would yield:

```
/*
// ==UserScript==
// @version       1.0
// ==/UserScript==
*/
alert("hello world");
```

which parses perfectly fine as a GM script. The metadata reads correctly.

Comment: This *almost* works.... If you're trying to use Sprockets, however, you'll run into erros with this approach (since `//= <something>` is replaced with the code of `<something>`, so you get

    /*
    //= require <something>
    */

-->

    /*
    (code of something)
    */

Comment: I doubt they are using sprockets for userscript development.

Comment: To emit `require` consumable by Sprockets (Rails asset pipeline), you can use `*=`, like so: https://gist.github.com/joliss/9480786 (in case anyone else is wondering)